# timezone conversion using date-fns

Tags: reactjs, timezone, date-fns

I’m trying to work with date-fns-tz in my react-based webpage and couldn’t make the following use-case to work.

I have a date input in a form that should be submitted to the backend that stores the data in local timezone.

A user in **GMT+2** timezone selects **14:00 on 1/Feb/2021** in the UI, which correlates to **1612180800** timestamp (as the UI was opened in GMT+2), but it should eventually get sent to the backend as 14:00 in **GMT-8**, which is actually **1612216800** timestamp.

What’s the right way to get this conversion (from 1612180800  --> 1612216800 ) to work?

I tried to work with various date-fns functions, but hadn’t found the right one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll need two things to make this work correctly:

- An IANA time zone identifier for the intended target time zone, such as `'America/Los_Angeles'`, rather than just an offset from UTC.

  - See "Time Zone != Offset" in [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).
- A library that supports providing input in a specific time zone.

  - Since you asked about date-fns, you should consider using the [date-fns-tz](https://github.com/marnusw/date-fns-tz) add-on library.
  - Alternatively you could use [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/index.html) for this.
  - In the past I might have recommended Moment with Moment-TimeZone, but you should review [Moment's project status page](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/) before choosing this option.

Sticking with date-fns and date-fns-tz, the use case you gave is the very one described in the docs for the [`zonedTimeToUtc`](https://github.com/marnusw/date-fns-tz#zonedtimetoutc) function, which I'll copy here:

> Say a user is asked to input the date/time and time zone of an event. A date/time picker will typically return a Date instance with the chosen date, in the user's local time zone, and a select input might provide the actual IANA time zone name.
>
> In order to work with this info effectively it is necessary to find the equivalent UTC time:
>
> ```js
> import { zonedTimeToUtc } from 'date-fns-tz'
>
> const date = getDatePickerValue() // e.g. 2014-06-25 10:00:00 (picked in any time zone)
> const timeZone = getTimeZoneValue() // e.g. America/Los_Angeles
>
> const utcDate = zonedTimeToUtc(date, timeZone) // In June 10am in Los Angeles is 5pm UTC
>
> postToServer(utcDate.toISOString(), timeZone) // post 2014-06-25T17:00:00.000Z, America/Los_Angeles
> ```

In your case, the only change is that at the very end instead of calling `utcDate.toISOString()` you'll call `utcDate.getTime()`.

Note that you'll still want to divide by 1000 if you intend to pass timestamps in seconds rather than the milliseconds precision offered by the `Date` object.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I tried your suggestion : `zonedTimeToUtc(1612180800, 'America/Los_Angeles').getTime()`, but it just get me to where I started from - **1612180800**, and I need to get to **1612216800** per the use-case I described.

Comment: OK, I think I have it.. I used you solution, and instead of inputing the explicit timestamp (1612180800), I used the date as string - "2021-02-01 14:00", and it seems to work

Comment: I believe that's be design.  You could also pass a `Date` object, and it would do that part for you ([see the source code here](https://github.com/marnusw/date-fns-tz/blob/16d088079596a6a0a2e75ddea29289ac747f9814/src/zonedTimeToUtc/index.js#L30-L32)).  Since a lot of date pickers return `Date` objects, that is probably your best bet.

Comment: Keep in mind that this is all still very much a workaround, and it can have edge cases that fail.  For example, if the user picks a time that's valid in the target time zone, but falls into a gap created by a forward transition in the *local* time zone (such as with the start of DST), then the resulting time will be an hour shifted after conversion.

Comment: Actually I don't use a date picker. I use a text field with type=time, and attach to it some day to construct my full date.  Is there a solution to the edge case you mentioned about DST transition?

Comment: `getTimeZoneValue()` how is this working?

Comment: @MuhammadRehanQadri - that is from the sample in the linked doc.  It does not presume to offer an implementation.  Neither does `getDatePickerValue()`.  Both are implied that they are part of the user's code.

Answer (score -9):

You can use 'moment' to convert timezone.

1.Create a moment with your date time, specifying that this is expressed as utc, with moment.utc()

2.convert it to your timezone with moment.tz()

For example

```
moment.utc(t, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
    .tz("America/Chicago")
    .format('l');
```

Comment: It didn't quite work. This is what I tried: `moment.tz(moment.utc(moment(1612180800*1000)),'America/Los_Angeles').format('MM-DD hh:mm')`, and it indeed converted 14:00 (GMT+2) to 04:00 (GMT-8) , but what I need is the **timestamp representation** of 14:00  in GMT-8, which is 1612216800.

Comment: Hi.  Please refer to [Moment's project status page](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/).  On StackOverflow, please refrain from recommending Moment as a solution unless Moment is specifically asked for in the question.  Thanks.