# date-fns How to get the end of day with the format 00:00:00 insted of 23:59:59

Tags: javascript, momentjs, date-fns

I am replacing moment by date-fns and I would like to have the endOfDay formatted as moment.js does.

I mean moment.js gives me this 00:00:00
date-fns gives me this 23:59:59

moment.js

```
moment().endOf('isoWeek').startOf('day').toDate()
//output: 00:00:00
```

date-fns

```
export const thisWeekEndOn = () => {
    return endOfWeek(NEW_DATE, {weekStartsOn: monday});
}
//output: 23:59:59
```

I am not writing the full output of both functions, just the hour:min:sec

Comment: Some piece of code would be helpful here

Answer (score 11):

As per docs

---

the `endOfDay()` returns `23:59:59.999`:

```
// The end of a day for 2 September 2014 11:55:00:
const result = endOfDay(new Date(2014, 8, 2, 11, 55, 0))
//=> Tue Sep 02 2014 23:59:59.999
```

Docs: https://date-fns.org/v2.22.1/docs/endOfDay

---

While `startOfDay()` returns `00:00:00`

```
// The start of a day for 2 September 2014 11:55:00:
const result = startOfDay(new Date(2014, 8, 2, 11, 55, 0))
//=> Tue Sep 02 2014 00:00:00
```

Docs: https://date-fns.org/v2.22.1/docs/startOfDay

---

**You may want to use `startOfDay()` if you want `00:00:00` instead of using `endOfDay()` :)**

Comment: Thanks. I am usign start of day, but I need to get the end and start of a week, month, so on. If I use start of day, it gonna give the day after.

Comment: Start and end of date is tied to a timezone. How can I specify what timezone do I have in mind when asking for start/end of day?

Comment: @seawolf here are some references for timezone in date-fns  https://date-fns.org/v2.22.1/docs/Time-Zones, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66029964/timezone-conversion-using-date-fns

Comment: Also add `import { startOfDay } from 'date-fns'`

Answer (score 2):

#### It is not due to moment.js: it is due to the .startOf()

You suggest that `moment` is giving 0:00 for the end of the day, but your code shows that it is not.

You have asked for the end of a day *and then* asked moment for the *start* of that day.

```
//                        *******
moment().endOf('isoWeek').startOf('day').toDate()
//output: 00:00:00        *******
```

#### Achieving this with datefns

Can you use a similar construction in `datefns`?

For example, does this work for you?

```
export const thisWeekEndOn = () => endOfWeek(NEW_DATE, {weekStartsOn: monday});
```

Or this?

```
export const thisWeekEndOn = () => startOfDay(endOfWeek(NEW_DATE, {weekStartsOn: monday}));
```

Comment: It is not my code. The outoput I get when I console the moment function, is 00:00:00. I was surpprised, but because it shows me that, I was trying to get the same from date-fns to keep the same result as moment. 

I am in charge of replace moment by date-fns and it is the first time I am using both.

Comment: Updated: if it worked, please mark as correct.

Comment: ```export const thisWeekEndOn = () => {
    return endOfWeek(NEW_DATE, {weekStartsOn: monday});
}```

That worked for me.

Comment: Ah, great! That makes clearer what you were aiming for. It would be good to mark as correct if it now reflects a correct answer.

Comment: Eureka I was wondering how to do it... :)

Comment: Please click the grey checkmark icon. Described here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work